# Send float with Serial Port

Tags: stm32, serial, data

I'm trying to send float temperature data from stm32f103c8t6 to qt application. When I try tosee value with Keil I can. But When I try to transmit to App I got some error about convering uint8_t to float. How can I send Float data to app with serial port?

```
     //variables
        uint16_t readValue;
        float tCelsius;

while (1)
  {  HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,1000);
    readValue = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
    tCelsius = 357.558 - 0.187364 * readValue;
        
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, (uint8_t *)tCelsius, 16, 500);
        
    

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
```

Comment: That code is converting a float value to a pointer from which 16 bytes are sent. First of all, floats are not 16 bytes, and you might want to send data from the address of the float variable, not from the address stored in the float variable.

Comment: What format should the floating point number be sent as?  A text string like "1.035434" (in this case, 8 bytes), a 32 bit binary value representing the actual floating point register value, or (since you only have a 12 bit ADC value) just a 12 or 16 bit integer containing the fixed point value?  All of these are reasonable but you have to know which (or pick) one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sprintf to convert to char, however sprintf can take considerable microprocessor resources on smaller micros such as the 100 series, it would be better to send it as a float and convert it in qt.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use the float as an address for your data and then send it over serial. It is expecting (a pointer to) a string, so you should provide one.

You can just create a transmit buffer (ex. char txbuf[64]) and then use [sprintf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm) to format the float into a string and put it in the buffer. Then, you can send this formatted string using UART_Transmit.

Here is an example from my code:

```
uint8_t txbuf[64];

sprintf((char*)txbuf, "Returned: %f\r\n", meas_flt);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, txbuf, strlen((char*)txbuf), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
```

If using STM32CubeIDE, you will need to enable using floats with printf using the flag -u_printf_float. This can be enabled in the MCU Settings tab in the project settings.

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: The float is not used as integer and sent, the float is used as pointer to memory address from which data is sent. And %i is for printing integers, not floats. How do you know the receiver expects a string? It can be assumed to receive a binary float too

Comment: @Justme Yes I see that, I did not read the code very carefully the first time. I have corrected the format option in my example code. Sure, technically the receiver could expect anything, but I have never seen a receiver in practice ever expect anything other than a string.